# SpringBoot: can't create ear with maven: Unable to deduce layout

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, ear

I have a SpringBoot project with the war and ear module, that I build using maven ( a build automation tool used primarily for Java projects.) and IntelliJ IDEA This is my pom.xml of the war project:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
            <parent>
                <groupId>com.bendiciones</groupId>
                <artifactId>bendiciones-parent</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </parent>

            <artifactId>bendiciones-ear</artifactId>
            <packaging>ear</packaging>


            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.bendiciones</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bendiciones-war</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                    <type>war</type>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>





 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>${project.build.finalName}-${project.version}</finalName>
                    <earSourceDirectory>src/main/resources</earSourceDirectory>
                    <packagingExcludes>**/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>com.bendiciones</groupId>
                            <artifactId>bendiciones-war</artifactId>
                            <contextRoot>/bendiciones</contextRoot>
                            <bundleFileName>bendiciones.war</bundleFileName>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <preparationGoals>clean install</preparationGoals>
                    <arguments>-DaltDeploymentRepository=releases::default::http://el1881.bc:8081/nexus/content/repositories/MicroserviceReleases</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <layout>NONE</layout>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>bendiciones</finalName>
    </build>


        </project>
```

But when I build the class I have this error:

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.5.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) on project bendiciones-ear: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.5.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to deduce layout for '/bendiciones/bendiciones-ear/target/bendiciones-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear' -> [Help 1]
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.5.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) on project bendiciones-ear: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.5.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to deduce layout for '/bendiciones/bendiciones-ear/target/bendiciones-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear'
     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
```

Comment: Building a spring boot jar/war in the same project as the ear does not make sense. Separate module which creates the war (spring boot) and another which creates the ear (as you already done more or less which defining the dependency to the war file) and looking into your configuration why do you have the spring-boot-plugin in that module and configured to skip it? Why not removing the configuration at all of spring-boot-maven-plugin? Why do you have packaging excludes in maven-ear-plugin configuration? Also strongly recommend to use the most recent versions  https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: why did you include spring-boot-maven-plugin when you are trying to create a EAR

Comment: I've remove it with the same result :-(

Comment: You have remove the spring-boot-maven-plugin and got that same message about execution of spring-boot-maven-plugin? If so you are inheriting the configuration from your parent which means the parent is wrong...

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the following from your top pom...

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Why would you want to remove a plugin? Please give a possible explanation on this. "The repackage goal of the spring-boot-maven-plugin must be configured to run first in order to create the required executable archive."